# XNA flushing screen after 20 seconds

Tags: forms, xna, picturebox, dispose

I run my XNA game from inside a PictureBox in Windows Forms project. After launching it runs well for about 20 seconds and then suddenely everything disappears and you can see the default Cornflower Blue screen. I checked every timer and dispose usage, but found nothing. What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We can't really help you without any code.
It would be nice if u posted a part of it.(where u think or know it goes wrong).

Comment: You'll have to post some of your code for anyone to determine what the problem may be. However, 20 seconds sounds like a possible duration for GC collection to kick in. Is your Game a field/property? Check things like this, make sure nothing's loosing reference.

Comment: I keep my game as a field in Forms project. Actually it's quite big right now, so that's why I didn't post any code. I have no clue where the problem could be. But I paused debugging after this blue page occured and all of my items are there. No values were changed, just the screen turns blue. The game seems to run in background. I was considering it to be GC, but all objects still exist, they just disappear.

Comment: I keep everything in LevelOne class which inherits from Level class and level class inherits from ScreenView : DrawableGameComponent. I checked, Dispose isn't invoked on ScreenView so it must be something else.

Comment: And you're certain that the Draw methods are actually being run? If so, all I can think of, is that it must be loosing its connection to the PictureBox. Ensure the Handle in Game is still pointing at the PictureBox. Maybe it changed Handle value? (I don't know if that's even possible. Maybe if it gets reinstatiated?)

Comment: Yes, I checked, it invokes every Draw function from LevelOne to ScreenView. And also PictureBox and Handle are set. But I also tried launching only XNA game, without linking it to Forms and this problem also occures. Can it be connected with mabe overloading the Content Manager? I have many icle blocks on the board and I call loading resources every time. Do you thing that this could be the problem?

Comment: Ok, so I found an old version of this game. I didn't change anything with linking XNA with Forms, without adding TabControl to the constructor(I know it's probably naive:)), so that shouldn't be the problem. And the old version works well. Mabe you could look inside the code and tell me what may cause this problem?
old version(working): [link](http://pastebin.com/NT9k6NfE)
current(not working): [link](http://pastebin.com/P24dPdDB)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why are you using pictureBox. You must create your own control which will handle a game window inside a form.

Check [this source code of game inside winforms](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=59802AFBA7F9048E&id=59802AFBA7F9048E!121)

It looks like:

[image: result]

The source of game draw control originally written by microsoft.